# Arranging $n$ items, that can be one of three colors, in a symmetrical pattern.

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

In how many ways can $n$ items, that can be one of three colors, be arranged so that there is symmetry in the pattern of the arrangement?

I'm attempting to solve this problem by breaking it down into three cases where $n$ is zero, odd or even. I know that there is $\binom{3}{0}$ choice for the color of an item when $n = 0$ and $\binom{3}{1}$ choices for the color of an item when $n > 0$, but I'm having difficulties formally proving the symmetric pattern of an arrangement.

Comment: What do you mean by symmetry?

Comment: You need to define what you mean by symmetry in the pattern.  Do you mean the pattern is a palindrome, that it is the same if it is reversed?  If so, the pattern is defined by the first half (rounded up).  If $n$ is odd and you have an odd number of each color you will fail.  Thinking about that may lead you to the whole answer in this case.

Comment: Yes. Sorry for misspeaking. The pattern would be a palindrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not given a number of items of each color, you can choose the first $\lceil \frac n2 \rceil$ items as you wish, then the rest have to reflect the first ones.  There are therefore $3^{\lceil \frac n2 \rceil}$ palindromic arrangements of length $n$ and $3$ colors.